# Running MMU less Linux on Cortex-R4

Tags: embedded, arm, linux

I'm using ARM Cortex-R4 for my system. I'm little bit confused about which linux should I go for - Standard Linux Kernel with MMU disabled or uCLinux.

On an eval board, I have run the standard kernel compiled with MMU disabled. I used cramfs filesystem which available on the official ARM website. After the kernel boots up, I receive the shell but I couldn't do much experimentation as I found that most of the time, the shell stops responding (particularly when I press  for auto-completion).

So, I'm still not sure whether MMU less kernel shall run smoothly if I use correct filesystem. Also, which distro (buildroot?) should I use for the no-VM Linux?

Any idea or suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ucLinux is not only a kernel, but the surrounding distribution. Since user space programs have to be modified to work well without a MMU due to differences in the semantics of mmap, fork and such, going MMU-less is more than just compiling a kernel differently.

If you're using ucLinux (the distro), can you pull a "vanilla" kernel from kernel.org and use that, compiled MMU-less? That's a good question for their mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I can't help you so much..

I had experience only with uClinux on an ARM7 NXPLCP2468 supplied with this board http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/kits/lpc2468_kit.php .

My experience is that this kind of block appear often on this kind of linux, and aren't always predictable.
I've made some test with simple calculus of mathematical function like FFT written in c and compiled with gcc, but I got so many problem, kernel panic and so on.
In conclusion, I'm switched to Linux running on an ARM9.

My suggestion is to put a lot of ram on your board and read with attention all the note about the difference between uClinux and Linux.